# Sequelize model to null / empty

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have build a model with the following code:

```
const sUser = User.build();
```

After a user has logged in, the model is filled.

```
sUser.id = user.id; // 39
sUser.email = email; //example@stockoverflow.com
...
```

If the user logs out, I want to set the model to NULL because I have the problem that when the client sign in again (with other account) after logout `sUser.id` is not changed during login.

```
sUser.id = user.id; // 39 - still ID like before logout
sUser.email = email; //NEWEXAMPLE@stockoverflow.com - is changed
...
```

`sUser.email` and all other fields can be changed without problems but `sUser.id` cannot.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have created a new js object called (sUser) and remove the sequelize object from sUser.
Works now without isses.